# Inherited method list in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, shortcut

In a C# file, is there any way to show class methods, including those from super class?
`Ctrl + Shift + O` only shows methods in current file.

Comment: I assume you've installed https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-dotnettools.csharp? And you are aware of Visual Studio Community (https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) and decided not to use it.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen you're right, I'm not using Visual Studio Community but Visual Studio Code

Comment: Related GH issue for adding inherited members to outline view: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/157461